# Cleanest Code in Android Java to Upload Image Selected from ActivityResultLauncher to PHP Server?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uri, okhttp

I would like to write the simplest code where the image that a user selected through ActivityResultLauncher will be sent to my own PHP server and be stored there.
I have written the code below, and I have kept making small changes to it but none of them works. To avoid burdening every one, I am not posting my PHP codes but I believe they are correct, meaning there must be some bugs below in my code.
Can anyone help me and tell me what I have done wrong. I will be happy too if you can share me an entirely different way of doing it.
Thanks a lot!!!

```
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
                    File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                    builder.addFormDataPart("fileToUpload", "test.jpg", requestBody);
                    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://www.myphp.php")
                            .post(builder.build())
                            .build();
                    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: how about you provide some logging to log whenever something goes wrong? ignoring exceptions will not help you figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Uri.getPath() does not give you a file system path. You can easily check that using File.exists() before uploading.

Comment: Why didnt you implement onResponse() and onFailure()? Now you know nothing.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for the File.exists() suggestion. I just tried that right now and the answer is No. So I guess that means no file was generated with File(uri.getPath()). What next then?

Comment: Generated? Of course not. That will never generate/create a file. I only said that you used a wrong/not existing/impossible path.

Comment: You should not try to get a 'path' for that uri. That uri -Uri.toString()- is a nice content scheme. Use it directly to upload that file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works for me to select images from the local library which is an amalgamation of several modified snippets I have over the years. Not the cleanest I have but so far, it works for API 24 and up.

**ActivityResultLauncher variable**

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> uploadL = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        String s = getPath(uri);
                        //NOTE: use the 'path' variable to create a temporary file for uploading
                        String path = s == null ? uri.getPath() : s;
                    }
                });
```

**Call on your button onClickListener or the likes**

```
upload.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            uploadL.launch(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                    .setType("image/*"));
        });
```

**getPath() - check the varying URI schemes of the image**

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            } else return getPathIn(uri);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        } else {
            return getPathIn(uri);
        }
    }
```

**getPathIn() method - for temporary copying the selected file into memory**

```
public String getPathIn(Uri uri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = getContext().getContentResolver().
                openFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(parcel.getFileDescriptor());

        File file_cache = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), getFileName(uri));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file_cache);

        copyData(in, out);

        return file_cache.getPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**The rest of the utility methods for the aforementioned main functions**

```
public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void copyData(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}

public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

P.S. You do not need to ask for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission nor declare it in manifest if you are targeting for Android API 24 and up. Also, you can put the `getPath()`, `getPathIn()` and the rest of its support methods in a utility class for cleaning it up.